# How to install PL/CTL language into PostgreSQL database 8.1.22

Tags: database, function, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

Hi I am using postgresql 8.1.22, I am trying to setup postgresql auditing using the following function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.if_modified_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $body$
DECLARE
    v_old_data TEXT;
    v_new_data TEXT;
BEGIN
    /*  If this actually for real auditing (where you need to log EVERY action),
        then you would need to use something like dblink or plperl that could log outside the transaction,
        regardless of whether the transaction committed or rolled back.
    */

    /* This dance with casting the NEW and OLD values to a ROW is not necessary in pg 9.0+ */

    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        v_old_data := ROW(OLD.*);
        v_new_data := ROW(NEW.*);
        INSERT INTO audit.logged_actions (schema_name,table_name,user_name,action,original_data,new_data,query) 
        VALUES (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT,TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT,session_user::TEXT,substring(TG_OP,1,1),v_old_data,v_new_data, current_query());
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        v_old_data := ROW(OLD.*);
        INSERT INTO audit.logged_actions (schema_name,table_name,user_name,action,original_data,query)
        VALUES (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT,TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT,session_user::TEXT,substring(TG_OP,1,1),v_old_data, current_query());
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        v_new_data := ROW(NEW.*);
        INSERT INTO audit.logged_actions (schema_name,table_name,user_name,action,new_data,query)
        VALUES (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT,TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT,session_user::TEXT,substring(TG_OP,1,1),v_new_data, current_query());
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE
        RAISE WARNING '[AUDIT.IF_MODIFIED_FUNC] - Other action occurred: %, at %',TG_OP,now();
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN data_exception THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[AUDIT.IF_MODIFIED_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [DATA EXCEPTION] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
        RETURN NULL;
    WHEN unique_violation THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[AUDIT.IF_MODIFIED_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [UNIQUE] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
        RETURN NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[AUDIT.IF_MODIFIED_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [OTHER] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
        RETURN NULL;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
```

But if you observe in the above function current_query() is not coming with the mentioned language plpgsql. It throws some error. When I googled I found that in order to use current_query() function PL/CTL language must be installed. I tried to install as mentioned below. It throws an error. So kindly help me how to install PL/CTL language into my database so that current_query() function should work

```
-bash-3.2$ createlang -d dbname pltcl
createlang: language installation failed: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pltcl": No such file or directory
```

Okay as you suggested I created that current_query() function,but this time I got some thing like this , What i did is ,

```
CREATE TABLE phonebook(phone VARCHAR(32), firstname VARCHAR(32), lastname VARCHAR(32), address VARCHAR(64));


CREATE TRIGGER phonebook_auditt AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON phonebook 
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func();



INSERT INTO phonebook(phone, firstname, lastname, address) VALUES('9966888200', 'John', 'Doe', 'North America');
```

for testing the function i created a table named phonebook and created a trigger so that the function mentioned above audit.if_modified_func() will be executed after any insert or update or delete.the row is getting inserted but I am getting a error reg the audit.if_modified_func() function .the error is as follows

```
WARNING:  [AUDIT.IF_MODIFIED_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [OTHER] - SQLSTATE: 42703, SQLERRM: column "*" not found in data type phonebook

Query returned successfully: 1 rows affected, 10 ms execution time.
```

Kindly tell me what can i do to get rid of the above error.

Comment: Or to be precise: update ***now***

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you found the information about current_query and pltcl. These are unrelated. The reason why you can't find pltcl is simply because you're using too old PostgreSQL. current_query() has been added to Pg in version 8.4.

Is there any particular reason why you're using such old version? It is no longer supported, and it lacks almost 8 years of added features!

If you have to use 8.1, you might want to define:

```
create function current_query() returns text as '
select current_query from pg_stat_activity where procpid = pg_backend_pid();
' language sql;
```

But it is much better idea just to upgrade.

As for edited and added second question - it's very likely that Pg 8.1 cannot use "row.*" construct. Find who wrote the original code with the "dance comments", and ask about it. Perhaps it was meant to work in newer Pgs.